# Im trying to use .getName on a JButton, but it returns null, but when i do the toString it returns me all the right properties?

Tags: java, button, null

SOURCE:
javax.swing.JButton[,571,647,80x80,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=com.apple.laf.AquaButtonBorder$Toggle@1380cf2a,flags=288,maximumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=80,height=80],minimumSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=80,height=80],preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=80,height=80],defaultIcon=file:/Users/andreaks/Desktop/PreEntregaiDomino/build/classes/imagenes/A23.png,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=2,bottom=0,right=2],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=false,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=,defaultCapable=true]

NAME: null

the code im using is

```
private void JBsetseleccionadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object boton = evt.getSource();
    JButton este= (JButton) boton;

    seleccionado = este;
    System.out.println("SOURCE " + boton.toString());
    System.out.println("NAME " + este.getName());
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
String text = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
```

BTW, a better pattern for code like this is:

```
private JButton button;
button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener(new BListener());
private class BListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == button){
            //code for when the JButton button is pushed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**getComponentVariableName(component)**

IF you're using NetBeans or a similar IDE that by default creates private variables (fields) to hold references to all of your components, then you may be able to do something like this ...

```
private void JBsetseleccionadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object boton = evt.getSource();
    JButton este= (JButton) boton;

    seleccionado = null;
    System.out.println("SOURCE " + boton.toString());
    System.out.println("NAME " + Awt2.getComponentVariableName(boton));
    seleccionado = este;
}
```

The code to make the above code possible is as follows ...

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

/**
 * additional utilities for working with AWT/Swing.
 * this is a single method for demo purposes.
 * recommended to be combined into a single class
 * module with other similar methods,
 * e.g. MySwingUtilities
 *
 * @author http://javajon.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-awtswing-getcomponentvariablenamec.html
 */
public class Awt2 {

    /**
     * substitute for component.getName() when used in NetBeans or other IDE
     * that creates class fields to hold the components. uses reflection to
     * search through class fields for a match.
     * @param component the component to look for
     * @return hopefully the variable name used to hold this component
     */
    static public String getComponentVariableName(Object object) {

        if (object instanceof Component) {
            final Component component = (Component) object;
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // find the form where the variable name would be likely to exist
            final Component parentForm = getParentForm(component);

            // loop through all of the class fields on that form
            for (Field field : parentForm.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

                try {
                    // let us look at private fields, please
                    field.setAccessible(true);

                    // get a potential match
                    final Object potentialMatch = field.get(parentForm);

                    // compare it
                    if (potentialMatch == component) {

                        // return the name of the variable used
                        // to hold this component
                        if (sb.length() > 0) sb.append(",");
                        sb.append(field.getName());
                    }

                } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException 
                        | IllegalAccessException ex) {

                    // ignore exceptions
                }
            }

            if (sb.length() > 0) {
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

        // if we get here, we're probably trying to find the form
        // itself, in which case it may be more useful to print
        // the class name (MyJFrame) than the AWT-assigned name
        // of the form (frame0)
        final String className = object.getClass().getName();
        final String[] split = className.split("\\.");
        final int lastIndex = split.length - 1;
        return (lastIndex >= 0) ? split[lastIndex] : className;

    }

    /**
     * traverses up the component tree to find the top, which i assume is the
     * dialog or frame upon which this component lives.
     * @param sourceComponent
     * @return top level parent component
     */
    static public Component getParentForm(Component sourceComponent) {
        while (sourceComponent.getParent() != null) {
            sourceComponent = sourceComponent.getParent();
        }
        return sourceComponent;
    }
}
```

It uses reflection to look at all of the private variables on the form and try to match them to the component you are trying to identify.  If it finds a match, it returns the name of the java variable used to refer to the component.  If it finds two or more matches, it returns a comma separated list, which is why I added the `seleccionado = null;` into the first example.  If we put the code back the way it was...

```
private void JBsetseleccionadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object boton = evt.getSource();
    JButton este= (JButton) boton;

    seleccionado = este;
    System.out.println("SOURCE " + boton.toString());
    System.out.println("NAME " + Awt2.getComponentVariableName(boton));
}
```

The results may appear as like this...

```
SOURCE javax.swing.JButton[,6,6,126x28,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@7c0d41,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=What's my name?,defaultCapable=true]
NAME seleccionado,jButton1
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Although its a old question, i would still like to answer if it helps.

When you are adding the button, make sure you invoke the setName() function as under:

```
private void JBsetseleccionadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object boton = evt.getSource();
    JButton este = (JButton) boton;
    este.setName("button_name"); // set the name first

    seleccionado = este;
    System.out.println("SOURCE " + boton.toString());
    System.out.println("NAME " + este.getName());
}
```

That should resolve your issue and getName() should be able to provide the name. It is sort of weird but still the easiest way to get it done.